# substring() returns blank in hive

Tags: sql, hadoop, hive, substring, hiveql

I want to extract last 10 numbers from fields of a column, so I am using substring built in function in hive. But if the field value is less than the defined value(<10). Its returning a 'blank' field.
Input :
`orig_number
140976526012
140980434512
1740016
1740016
17250460171`

I am using this code.
`select *,length(orig_number) as leng,substr(orig_number,-10)  as subbstring from num_table sort by orig_number;` 
Output is:

`orig_number    leng    subbstring
140976526012    12     0976526012
140980434512    12     140980434512
1740016          7

1740016          7

17250460171     11     725046017`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Retrieve up to 10 characters from the end of the line

```
select  orig_number
       ,regexp_extract (orig_number,'.{1,10}$',0)   as orig_number_suffix 

from    num_table
;
```

---

```
+--------------+--------------------+
| orig_number  | orig_number_suffix |
+--------------+--------------------+
| 140976526012 |         0976526012 |
| 140980434512 |         0980434512 |
|      1740016 |            1740016 |
|      1740016 |            1740016 |
|  17250460171 |         7250460171 |
+--------------+--------------------+
```

---

https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/Hive/LanguageManual+UDF
https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html

---

And here is why you get a blank.
Seems to me like a bad design of the **substr** function.

[UDFSubstr.java](https://github.com/apache/hive/blob/ff67cdda1c538dc65087878eeba3e165cf3230f4/ql/src/java/org/apache/hadoop/hive/ql/udf/UDFSubstr.java)

```
private int[] makeIndex(int pos, int len, int inputLen) {
    if ((Math.abs(pos) > inputLen)) {
      return null;
    }

...
```

Comment: @TobySpeight - I've edited the answer. Being that said - **(1)** An answer's scope is subject to limitations of time, internet availability, computer availability and the quality/level of interest of the post itself. This specific answer was given from my cellphone while I was waiting for an elevator. **(2)** Please bear in mind that SO answer is not intended to function as a tutorial but to solve a specific problem. **(3)** I Invite you to take a look on some of my other answers